# Thymeleaf not showing values on Web with Springboot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to springboot and I'm trying to create a simple website with Springboot and Thymeleaf. I created a HTML table but my table is not being rendered in the web page. This is what I see [image], this is what it should look like [image].

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>listado de estudiantes</title>
</head>
<body>

       <tbody>
        <tr th:each="estudiante : ${estudiantes}">
            <td th:text="${estudiante.nombre}">Nombre</td>
            <td th:text="${estudiante.apellido}">apelido</td>
            <td th:text="${estudiante.email}">email</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

This is my POM [Thymeleaf dependency in Springboot](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc)

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Controller

```
package com.app.web.controlador;
import com.app.web.servicio.EstudianteServicio;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class EstudianteControlador {

    @Autowired
    private EstudianteServicio servicio;

    @GetMapping({"/estudiantes","/"})
    public String listarEstudiantes(Model modelo){
        modelo.addAttribute("estudiantes", servicio.listarTodosLosEstudiantes());
        return "estudiantes";
    }

}
```

Application properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_crud
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=%password%
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.show.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: also, do try logging or printing the output of servicio.listarTodosLosEstudiantes() to see if theres nothing wrong with the method

Comment: I think it might be that there is nothing to iterate over, so it defaults to showing the contents of the respective <td> tags